# CakePHP 3 - count on deep association

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have three tables `users`, `campaigns` and `videos`.

and their relation is like

```
users->hasMany('campaigns');
campaigns->hasMany('videos');
```

What I want is to select all users and count their `videos` records.

I can filter on particular table basis, like I can count `videos` records on `$this->Videos->find()`.

**But how to count deep related in CakePHP 3? ie., on `Users`?**

What I want like

```
User object => [
    'email' => 'email@example.com'
    'name' => 'My Name'
    'post_videos_count' => 10
]
User object => [
    'email' => 'email2@example.com'
    'name' => 'User 2'
    'post_videos_count' => 50
]
```

where `email` and `name` fields are from `Users` and `post_videos_count` contains the count of related videos.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507686/cakephp-3-contain-deep-associated-model-with-count?rq=1 probably the same

Answer (score 1):

Probably [contain](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain) & [count](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#query-count):

```
$query = $users->find()->contain(['Campaigns' => ['Videos' => function ($q) {
    return $q->count('Video.id');
}]]);
```

Comment: No, I don't want count of `campaigns` but `videos` which belongs to `campaigns` which further belongs to `users`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the counter cache behavior. It's efficient and the most easy solution.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html

Comment: can you give an example of how to actually use it in controller

Comment: Did you actually read the page I've linked? I don't think so, because it is obviously that this works different. Read the manual! Even my answer says *behavior*.